# MySQL JSON_SEARCH for multiple arguments of nested objects

Tags: mysql, sql, jsonpath, mysql-json, json-extract

I have a db-table containing json formated strings:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `template` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TemplateData` longtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);

INSERT INTO template (Id, TemplateData) VALUES
(1, '[]'),
(2, '[{"type":"template","id":1}]'),
(3, '[{"type":"other", "id":1}]'),
(4, '[{"type":"template","id":3},{"type":"template","id":1}]'),
(5, '[{"type":"template","id":2}]');
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/739f3a

For background: these records are templates for a frontend to build dynamic views. Every template is able to include another template. So based on above data, record #2 is a template using the other template #1 inside. View it like reusable parts.

Inside the json I have an array containing multiple types of objects. In my example are two different variants: `{type: "template", id: number}` and `{"type": "other", "id": number}`.

## Server-Architecture

#### Production:

MySQL Server Version 8.0.21.

#### Development:

MariaDB Server Version 10.4.11

## What i want to retrieve by SELECT

I need a list of all templates, which are using a specific other template. I want to select all records, which contain an object of `$[*].type='template'` AND `$[*].id=1`.

- Based on the given records, i want to retrieve rows #2 and #4, because both contain an object matching both arguments. Complication is on #4, having the record at array index 1.
- I don't want #1 because no element inside the array
- I don't want #3 because `$[0].type` is not template

## What I already tried

I made some tryouts using JSON_SEARCH() and JSON_EXTRACT(), but could not handle to get my expected rows:

```sql
SELECT
    Id,
    JSON_EXTRACT(TemplateData,
                 JSON_UNQUOTE(
                 REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(TemplateData,
                                     'all',
                                     'template'),
                         '.type"',
                         '.id"'))) AS includedTemplateId 
FROM    template 
HAVING  includedTemplateId = 1
```

returns only one record with Id:2 but not record with Id:4 because JSON_SEARCH with 'all' delivers an array of paths, but JSON_EXTRACT does not allow path to be an array.

## What is not possible

I also tried using a simple LIKE expression, but ended on the problem, if the order or the objects argument differ (p.e.: `{id: number, type: "template"}`) or a space or different quotes are used the like does not match.

## Additional goal

It would be the most perfekt result, if i get record #5 too for a search after template-id #1, because #5 uses #2, which uses #1. But this would be next level.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Does JSON_TABLE() is available?

Comment: sorry, added the requested versions. MySQL: 8.0.21 and MariaDB: 10.4.11
edit: MariaDB is the reason why field is defined as longtext and not as json

Comment: For this version parse all rows to separate template objects accompanied with original row id. Then use any common logical division technique.

Comment: Could you provide an example for what you have in mind? What do you mean by "separate template objects accompanied with original row id"?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for MySQL 8.0.21:

```
SELECT template.id
FROM template
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE( template.TemplateData,
                       "$[*]" COLUMNS( type VARCHAR(254) PATH "$.type",
                                         id INT PATH "$.id" )
                     ) AS jsontable
WHERE jsontable.type = 'template'
  AND jsontable.id = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52df954bb2d9884879a101e20186c09e)

If template objects may be duplicated in separate value then add DISTINCT.

---

> Any suggestion in regard of MariaDB?

Draft solution applicable to MariaDB.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE
cte1 AS ( SELECT MAX(LENGTH(TemplateData) - LENGTH(REPLACE(TemplateData, '{', ''))) max_obj_count
          FROM template ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT 1 num
          UNION ALL
          SELECT num + 1
          FROM cte2
          WHERE num < ( SELECT max_obj_count
                        FROM cte1 ) )
SELECT DISTINCT
       template.id
FROM template
CROSS JOIN cte2
WHERE LOCATE('"type":"template"' ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(template.TemplateData, '}', cte2.num), '{', -1))
  AND LOCATE('"id":1' ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(template.TemplateData, '}', cte2.num), '{', -1))
```

The problem - this code searches for `'"type":"template"'` and `'"id":1'` substrings strictly - i.e. it will not find the rows where the value is written as, for example, `'"type" : "template"'` (excess space chars) or `'"id":"1"'` (the value is quoted).

If you want to eliminate this problem then you must get `SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(template.TemplateData, '}', cte2.num), '{', -1)` in one more CTE, clear it from all `[]{}` chars, then wrap with `{}` and process this value in WHERE as JSON object.

Comment: Works (as you said for mysql). Interessting solution - Thanks! Any suggestion in regard of MariaDB?

Comment: @MIB For MariaDB you may generate natural numbers list from 1 till max. objects amount per value in CTE then process the string using common string functions (SUBSTRING_INDEX primarily) and extract separate objects and their attributes one object per row.

Comment: Sorry, but could you give an example for this suggestion too? I don't get, what you are suggesting.

Comment: @MIB Draft variant applicable at MariaDB (and of course at MySQL too) added.

Comment: wow, thats get really complicated. For the MYSQL-Solution it's clear how it works, but that for MariaDB is crazy. First part, you fetch the maximum amount of objects in the list, right? But what is happening after that? (sadly the solution itself seems good for the example but wont work for me, because the other objects inside the json have properties with deeper objects. The counting would fail on these.).

Comment: @MIB *First part, you fetch the maximum amount of objects in the list, right?* Yes, `cte1` did this. *But what is happening after that?* `cte2` generates natural numbers from 1 to the value obtained in `cte1`. Study [Recursive Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive). And execute replacing final query with simple `select * from cte2` and more complex `SELECT * FROM template CROSS JOIN cte2`.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for MySql 5.7 (and I think mariaDb too)

```
select tp.id,tp.TemplateData
from template tp
where json_contains( tp.TemplateData ,json_object('type','template','id',1))
;
```